# Reinstalling MySQL on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, installation, mysql-error-2002

MySQL is broken on my Ubuntu OS. It throws the following error:

```
mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I wasn't able to repair it. So I want to reinstall MySQL. But I didn't find an effective way.
I used `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server-5.1`,

But after the re-installation, it is still throwing the same error. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I change the passwrod,this may occur when i use some rails app,
in fact i have set a password for mysql,but when i execute rails rake:db:schema:crate, seems it set the password empty

Answer (score 1):

Restart mysqld.